# I want to merge two tables [Tabl1] and [Tabl2] and show result by ID where [Tabl1].[names] = 'any string name'?

Tags: sql-server-2008, select, union-all

In my example where name like '' show all value tabl2 with tabl1

```
SELECT * 
FROM
    (SELECT 
         ID, names, NULL AS address, work, note
     FROM   
         Tabl1
     UNION  
     SELECT 
         ID, name, address, NULL, NULL
     FROM   
         Tabl2) as x
ORDER BY 
    id, note DESC, address
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

With CTE_NAME(ID, names)  --Column names for Temporary table
AS
(
SELECT ID , NAME FROM TABLE1 
UNION
SELECT ID , NAME FROM TABLE2

)
SELECT * FROM CTE_NAME  --SELECT or USE CTE temporary Table
WHERE name = "x"
ORDER BY ID

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use UNION to combine the results of two queries. In your case:

```
SELECT ID, names, NULL AS address, work, note
FROM Tabl1
GROUP BY names
UNION ALL
SELECT ID, name, address, NULL, NULL
FROM Tabl2
GROUP BY Tabl3
```

Note - If you use UNION ALL as in above, it's no slower than running the two queries separately as it does no duplicate-checking.